# Dbms best practice

Tags: database

I have some questions about programming with a DBMS (no specific language needed, but I'm using Java; no specific DBMS in mind).

I open a transaction, select a row, then read a field, add 1 to the field, and update, then commit. What happens if another user runs in the same time a transaction on that field? Does it crash the transaction, or what?

Example: I'm a in a shop that has 1 kg of bread. Waiter1 has a client that needs 1 kg of bread. Waiter2 the same. If the program is:

```
select row "bread"
if quantity>=1 kg then quantity=quantity-1
update row
```

What happens if the two waiters run the transaction in the same time?

What are the best ways to implement multiuser, avoiding "collision"? Select and lock, transaction only, or what?

When to use optimistic lock, or pessimistic?

When to use lock, and when is it not needed?

Comment: Search for "sql transaction isolation level".

Answer (score 0):

Why are you handling this on the application side? Relational databases are built to handle situations like this. Just use an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET    quantity = quantity - 1
WHERE  item_name = 'bread' AND quantity >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Transaction Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)). The official SQL standard would handle it like this:

If you don't lock specifically your database will generally lock either the row or even the table for you. Depending on your isolation level it will either wait or raise an error.

**Serializable**

The second transaction will wait for the first to complete before it can do anything.

**Repeatable reads**

As soon as the first transaction reads, the second will wait until the first one committed. Or the other way around, if somehow the second transaction starts reading before the first.

**Read committed**

If the first transaction writes before the second writes, the first will have to wait until the second has committed. Otherwise the second will have to wait until the first has committed.

**Read uncommitted**

Both can read without an issue, but the first to write will make the other write stall till the transaction has been committed.

If one of the transactions commits after the other reads, you could lose the data and end up with only 1 update.